# Mixed linear model with Probabilistic Layers Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tensorflow-probability

I'm interested in fitting a linear mixed model using the variational inference capabilities of tensorflow probabilities and keras. However, I cannot find a straight-forward answer on how to implement such analysis. Using the regression example in TF probabilities (see [Case 3 here](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Probabilistic_Layers_Regression)), I am able to grasp how to fit these models if we have only random variables in the model (the example is regression using a single feature). Following the radon example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Linear_Mixed_Effects_Model_Variational_Inference.ipynb), we have two features: floor (fixed) and county (random). My understanding is the latter should only be passed to the denseVariational layers, while the former can be passed to a regular dense layer. So I guess I would have to jointly train two networks, one for fixed and one for the random features and some how merge their outputs.

So my questions are:
(1) If these are fit jointly can the same loss function be applied to both? I often see mean square error used, while in VI negative log likelihood is used (I think this equivalent to maximizing evidence of lower bound).
(2) Does the input need to be split before-hand and fed as input to two networks?